# Website showing desktop version on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, desktop

My website is showing fine responsive behavior when i change the width of my browser window. I also checked it under different view port widths on [this studio press responsive testing tool](http://www.studiopress.com/responsive/) it appears to be working fine. However, when some of my clients checked it on different phones particularly Galaxy S3, they see desktop version of the site, instead of mobile one.

Can somebody please point out what am i missing.

Comment: Please do not link to your web site. Questions should be self-contained. Please read: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need a viewport meta tag to tell the device at what scale it should show your website:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: It won't work on XHTML. In XHTML for sure <meta> tag should be closed '</meta>'.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"></meta>`